# Does the static method thread-safe?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I am reading this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16976618/how-to-make-static-method-thread-safe) post, which give the sample code as :

```
static void modifySharedResource(SomeClass sc)
    {
        //do something
        lock (_lock)
        {
            //where sc is modified
        }
    }
```

I am curious that, why this static method need a lock, does the static method thread-safe in this sample ?

I also read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8370636/is-static-method-thread-safe), but I didn't understand the answer.

Could anyone give more detailed information about my question, thanks !

Comment: looks like a singleton?

Comment: whether a method is thread safe or not depends on whether or not it accesses shared resources (e.x static variables,..). There is nothing to do with whether the method is static

Comment: some other method may be currently acting on the object `sc`.  Using the lock in both places ensures those operations don't occur at the same time.

Comment: @Jonesopolis Generally it would be the responsibility of the caller of this method to ensure that the provided parameter isn't being manipulated in another thread while this thread is running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether a method is thread safe or not depends on whether or not it accesses shared resources (e.x static variables,..). There is nothing to do with whether the method is static.

In your case, it's not sure to tell whether modifying `sc` is thread safe or not. It depends on how this parameter is created and passed in to the method. In most of the cases, it's problematic if the passed in parameter is shared. When we develop a function, we should ensure that there is no problem no matter how the function is used.

With your `lock` (I assume that `_lock` is a static variable), you still **don't** achieve thread safe if `sc` is shared and modified somewhere else on another thread.

With the method named `modifySharedResource` (the parameter is **shared**), I'm quite sure there is a problem if the parameter is also modified somewhere else on another thread.

In general, it's a bad practice to modify incoming parameters: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/245767/is-it-an-antipattern-modifying-an-incoming-parameter

Answer (score 0):

you have a misunderstanding with thread-safe, keyword `lock` marks bit in sync block index of own parameter (_lock in your code) and another `lock` can't pass until other lock release _lock and revert bit

Answer (score -1):

The issue here is that the `SomeClass` is not thread safe. The static method as you have it here is thread safe.

Comment: I am not sure how you concluded that the method with // do stuff is thread-safe.

Comment: As I said: `the method as you have it here` is thread safe. Unfortunately I can not give any advice for code that is not in the example! So `//do something` could be or could not be thread safe.